# Keyboard shortcut to edit text in Microsoft Visio 2013

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-visio-2013

When a shape that contains a text is selected, is there any keyboard shortcut to edit the text?

I.e., going from:

[image]

to

[image]

The keyboard shortcut  <kbd>Control</kbd>  +  <kbd>2</kbd> does the trick, however it switches to the text mode, which I do not want:

[image]

Comment: `F2` is for switching between text editing & shape selection mode. Doesn't it work ?

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like good catch, it works well, thanks!

Comment: np, posting as an answer for others to see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For switching between text editing and shape selecting modes in Microsoft Visio use <kbd>F2</kbd>

Source : [Keyboard Shortcuts for Visio](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Keyboard-shortcuts-for-Visio-ee952f31-7e3e-4564-8116-f3ecbb733cc1?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)